agGrid GridOption APIs not working after angular 16 upgrade
After angular 15 to 16 upgrade, ag-gridOption APIs throwing error:
ag-grid version:
"ag-grid-angular": "^32.1.0",
"ag-grid-community": "^32.1.0",
angular version: 16
agGrid GridOption APIs not working after angular 16 upgrade.
this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{}


this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(col);
this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(rowData);

Error:
Property 'setColumnDefs' does not exist on type 'never'.
this.gridOptions.columnApi.autoSizeAllColumns();

Error:
Property 'columnApi' does not exist on type 'GridOptions'.
